# How to break an equation with an alignment at a specific symbol, whilst also aligned with a system of equations

Tags: equations, align, split

I have the following code

```
\begin{align}
K & = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sum^{19}_{i=1}\left(I_{i,p}\dot{x}^2_{i,p} + I_{i,s}\dot{x}^2_{i,s}\right) + g^2I_{19}\dot{x}^2_{19} +  \sum^{23}_{i=20}I_i\dot{x}^2_i \right] \label{eq: lagrange kinetic} \\
%
\begin{split}
    V & = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sum^{18}_{i=1}\left(k_{i,p}\left(x_{i+1,p} - x_{i,p} \right)^2+k_{i,s}\left(x_{i+1,s} - x_{i,s} \right)^2\right) + k_{19}\left(x_{20} - gx_{19} \right)^2 \right. \\
    & + \left. \sum^{22}_{i=20}k_i\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right)^2 \right] \label{eq: lagrange potential}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Which yields the following result. As you can see I would like to have both equations aligned with respect to each other (which they currently are), and the last equation broken at the indicated point and alliged at the sum symbol (as shown in a crude manner below).

[image]

I have tried the `aligned` environment, but that does not seem to do anything significantly different compared to the `split` environment in this case. I have alse tried to insert some phantom characters after the `+` sign, using `\vphantom` as a work-around in order to try and push the sum notation back, however that does not change anything (oddly enought).

Any ideas?

Comment: Unlrelated: you should not be splitting those `\left ... \right` like that there is no guarantee that `\left . ... \right]` has the same size as the first one. It is probably better to manually scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest an `aligned` within the `split`. I wouldn't align the sums but you can pick up the version you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % for more generous margins
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
K & = \frac{1}{2} \biggl[ \, \sum^{19}_{i=1} (I_{i,p}\dot{x}^2_{i,p} + I_{i,s}\dot{x}^2_{i,s}) + g^2 I_{19}\dot{x}^2_{19} +  \sum^{23}_{i=20}I_i\dot{x}^2_i \biggr]
\\ % what I would do
\begin{split}
    V & = \frac{1}{2}\biggl[
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    &\sum^{18}_{i=1}\Bigl( k_{i,p} (x_{i+1,p} - x_{i,p})^2 + k_{i,s} (x_{i+1,s} - x_{i,s})^2\Bigr) + k_{19}(x_{20} - g x_{19})^2 \\
    &+ \sum^{22}_{i=20} k_i (x_{i+1}-x_i)^2 \biggr]
    \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\\ % what you seem to prefer
\begin{split}
    V & = 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{1}{2}\biggl[
    &\sum^{18}_{i=1}\Bigl( k_{i,p} (x_{i+1,p} - x_{i,p})^2 + k_{i,s} (x_{i+1,s} - x_{i,s})^2\Bigr) + k_{19}(x_{20} - g x_{19})^2 \\
    + &\sum^{22}_{\mathclap{i=20}} k_i (x_{i+1}-x_i)^2 \biggr]
    \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]